# cassandra database design

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql, cql3

Consider the following situation:

I have a page it will have following fields:

```
pageid, title, content, like, follow, field1, field2..., field100, pagecomments, images
```

Like and follow is counter field that will increase on each click.

Now i am thinking of designing this in `Cassandra` in following ways:

```sql
**TYPE A** page_table { 
    page_id, 
    title, 
    content, 
    like, 
    follow,
    posted_by,
    datetime,
    image1,
    image2,
    field1,
    field2..., 
    field100
}

page_comments {
    commentid, 
    page_id,text, 
    comment_like, 
    posted_by,
    datetime
}

**TYPE B** page_table {
    page_id, 
    title, 
    content,
    posted_by,
    datetime,
    image1,
    image2,
    field1,
    field2...,
    field100
}

page_like {
    page_id, 
    like
}
page_follow {
    page_id, 
    follow
}

page_comments {
    commentid, 
    page_id,
    text, 
    comment_like, 
    posted_by,
    datetime
}
```

Which one is best way? Or suggest some good `Cassandra` database design for this, using `CQL`

Comment: How will you query the data?

Comment: Well, one query is obvious since he will have a web page presenting those following fields as he says.

Comment: my query should fetch **page_id, title, content,posted_by,datetime,image1,image2,field1,field2..............,field100 ,like,follow,commentid, page_id,text, comment_like, posted_by,datetime** of that particular page

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read up on some noSQL patterns

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/Patterns-Page

If you are going to get all the comments from a page, I don't see any FK's to the comments, which you will need in the `page_table` which brings to lite, that page is missing a pattern. I will add which is a `toMany` in `nosql` is frequenly embedded in the row, rather than having an index. So you have this in alot of designs.

```
page_table {  
    page_id, 
    title, 
    content, 
    like, 
    follow,
    posted_by,
    datetime,
    image1,
    image2, 
    fktocomment1, 
    fktocomment2, 
    fktocomment3 
}
```

What is typically done is the `fktocomment1` is prefexied with the word "comment" so you can find all the fks by stripping off the comment part and using the fk at the end(There is NO value!).
It is a composite name pattern which you can google.

**EDIT:** patterns page edited/added that pattern it was so common, I never thought to add it before.

Comment: I am using cassandra and As far as i know, cassandra doesn't have concept of Foreign Key. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: cassandra does NOT support Foreign Key "constraints" but people still use foreign keys in nosql all the time.  On Most models, you hardly ever can denormalize it all into one table so you end up with foreign keys.

Comment: even your model above had foreign keys ;).  in your comment_id table you have a foreign key page_id to refer back to the page row for that comment.

Comment: yah that is true that 'page_id' is what it is in 'page_table' but it not like FK as it happens in RDBMS am i right? means cassandra doesnt check this constraint its up to you how you manage, am i going right?

Comment: yes, there is not constraint checking in noSQL solutions and it is up to you to manage(and sometimes you manage data corruption around that stuff but it is not a big deal typically, just typical operations and management...losing the constraint checking has not been a big issue)